# Javascript function affecting other areas of page than what is specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<div id="logo"><!-- logo -->
<a href="index.php" id="ajax_link">My Site</a>
</div><!-- end logo -->

<?php
if ($_SESSION['uid'] == "") 
    {
        echo "<div id='main_menu' class='log'>You are not logged in &bull; <a href='login.php'>Login</a><br \></div>";
        exit();
    }
else 
    {
        echo "
            <div id='main_menu'>
            <ul>
            <li class='bar'>&nbsp;</li>
            <li><a href='index.php' id='ajax_link'>Edit Site</a></li>
            <li class='bar'>&nbsp;</li>
            <li><a href='docs.php' id='ajax_link'>My Documents</a></li>
            <li class='bar'>&nbsp;</li>
            <li><a href='contacts.php' id='ajax_link'>Web Contacts</a></li>
            <li class='bar'>&nbsp;</li>
            <li><a href='social.php' id='ajax_link'>Social Media</a></li>
            <li class='bar'>&nbsp;</li>
            You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['username']." &bull; <a href='logout_parse.php'>Logout</a><br \>
            </ul>
            </div>
        ";
    }
?>
```

I've got this menu system built(above) and i'm using ajax and jquery to change in and out the main content(below) depending on the menu item selected.

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#ajax_link').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });
    $('a').click(function(){                      
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length);
        function loadContent() 
        {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() 
        {
            $('#content').fadeIn('normal');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

however for some reason this code is affecting the login and logout links as well and i don't want that to happen.

I only recently added #ajax_links to try fix this problem as i was using #main_menu ul li a and #logo a before.

Can anyone tell me how i can fix this

Comment: `$('#ajax_link').each` will only select one element as IDs are unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `id` attribute should be unique. Change all those links to use a class instead:

```
<li><a href='index.php' class='ajax_link'>Edit Site</a></li>
```

Now use that to improve the selector

```
$('a.ajax_link').click(function(){          
   ....
```

And

```
$('.ajax_link').each(function(){
   ....
```

Comment: Ok I should have seen that i'm just getting bleary eyed looking at it too long. I've changed it now but it still isn't working.

Comment: As in it goes to index.php/#login.php rather than just login.php